# security - how to secure api key in HTTP GET request

Tags: security, ssl, hash, md5

I'm new to cryptography and I'm trying to prevent against man-in-the-middle-attack in a web service I'm developing. The way the web service work is that a user registers on the service using his email address and password and creates an application. Each application is given an application id and an application key. The application id is public (that's how the public communicates with that application) but the application key is private. The user credits his application by loading a pin (a 16 digit numeric string). Loading the pin is done via a HTTP Get request.

Now here is my question: how can the user do a HTTP GET request with his application id (the way the server identifies the application) and his application key (the way the server authenticates him) without compromising his application key?

Because our server has SSL (and I read that SSL protects against man-in-the-middle-attack), I was thinking about simply having users submit their application id and application key as parameters in the GET request, but after reading around, I decided this may not be secure. This is also because after doing the HTTP GET request to load the pin, the user may configure his account that we submit the server response via another HTTP GET request to a URL of his choice. And since we want to do an echo back of his application id and application key so he can authenticate that the request was really from us, I was worried his key might be compromised.

So I decided we should have the user do a md5 hash of his app id and app key to provide a hashed parameter and submit that instead of his app key in the GET request. Then on our server, since we already know the user's app id and app key, we can simply do an md5 hash of both and compare it with the hash parameter the user submitted. But then I also thought that may be insecure because if someone intercepts the hash parameter, the attacker can use that same hash parameter to submit several requests since the app id and app key is static. So in the long run, the hash parameter is no different from the app key.

Now I'm thinking, we should have the user do a md5 hash of his app id, his app key and the pin he wants to load to get the hash parameter. This way, since the pin is always different each time, even if an attacker intercepts a request, the authentication process would not be compromised for other requests because the attacker would not be able to reuse that hash with other requests.

For example, if a user has the following credentials:
1. app_id: 1234
2. app_key: bghuTHY678KIjs78

And a user wants to load the pin: 1234567890123456

He generates the hash by doing an md5 hash of "1234:bghuTHY678KIjs78:1234567890123456". That gives him 210a4c92d85473af9d5f48b4ee182ddd. Then he does a HTTP Get request to the address below:

https://example.com/process?app_id=1234&pin=123456789012&hash=210a4c92d85473af9d5f48b4ee182ddd

Is this method secure? Or should I simply just have the users submit their app id and app key in the HTTP GET request since we have SSL?

Comment: This kind of questions are better asked at security.stackexchange.com because. There you will also find several questions already dealing with similar issues, like http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71975/how-much-does-a-get-request-over-https-reveal-to-an-eavesdropper

Comment: md5 is very week with you should be using at least sha256. hmac with sha256 is one of the signing algorithms used with JWS the json web signing protocol so consider using that.

Comment: Thanks @simbo1905 I think I'll use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user secret should never be sent over the network. Instead, ask the user to *sign* his requests using his secret. HMAC is the relevant algorithm.

By the way, MD5 is obsolete and insecure for all crypto needs.

Comment: See the downvoted (not sure why it's downvoted) response from @simbo1905 below. 

Relying on HMAC alone (better than MD5 or plain session ids) requires both the client and the server to have knowledge of the "secret." 

A zero-knowledge proof (SRP6a mentioned below) authentication is superior.  Zero-knowledge proofs like SRP6a (which is quite old now, but has the most widespread implementations) or OPAQUE (better, but not implemented as widely) prevent the server from having the "secret" or the "plain hashes" in the event of a server breach.  SRP6a is closer to diffie-hellman vs. a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Secure Remote Password (SRP6a)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) and register a password verifier and salt for the 16 digit pin. The pin you never send to the server (you can store it in browser local storage for convenience of the user). Then authenticate the client using SRP6a which results in a strong shared secret session key for each successful authentication. Then use HMAC SHA256 to sign API calls using the session key. See the [thinbus-srp](https://bitbucket.org/simon_massey/thinbus-srp-js) JavaScript library and its demos of using SRP6a to authenticate resulting in a session key. See the [JWS "HS256"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) (HMAC with SHA-256, 256+ bit secret) algorithm and any library implementing that as an example of signing a web API with a shared secure key.

The SRP6a authentication protocol is a secure zero-knowledge password-proof where the server does not know the password. The server issues a random challenge to the client which generates a password-proof based on the challenge. The server uses the verifier the client provided for their password to check the password-proof. If the 16 digit pin uses uppercase letters like a standard software license key it is infeasible to run a dictionary attack on the verifier. Use the modern browser [webcrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) secure random number generator to generate the pin at the browser. Even you won't be able to obtain the password.

The overhead of using SRP6a to authenticate is that you need the client to first fetch the server challenge. The benefit for your use case is that if the client provides a good password-proof based on the challenge the both the client and server share a secure session key. No-one intercepting the traffic can know the session key. With that shared secret you can sign and verify every API call and verify the signature at the server. No-one intercepting any part of any exchange between you and the client end-to-end from registration through to usage can gain any advantage.

Comment: If people are going to vote down they should give a reason. SRP and JWS are proven technologies so I really don't see why anyone would vote down this answer which explains how do make and share a session key to secure a web API.

Comment: I voted you up as I feel this is a much better answer!  SRP6a has only been around for over two decades and (IMHO) is far superior to simple hashes (granted OPAQUE and other PAKEs are better than SRP).  The move towards zero-knowledge proofs like SRP6a is really needed!  The major benefit:  The actual "secret" never traverses the network, is not stored on the server, and provides a bit of defense against a MITM attack!